# Get Name of Most Recent Class Declaration?

Tags: php, introspection

I know this might be a long shot, but I am hoping that this is possible. This is not really a stumbling block in the project I am developing (though it could really help), but I am curious.

I want to get the name of the class being declared most recently. Basically, I have a piece of code that I need to append right after certain files containing declarations of certain (not all) classes. This piece of code is repeating, except for the class being initiated in it.

I have tried `get_declared_classes()` but the array is sorted alphabetically, and not in the sequence of when the classes are declared.

Here is a sample code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
class MyClass{

}

//Repeating code:

if(isset($_REQUEST['fxn'])){

    $class = new MyClass(); //I am hoping to make the class name dynamic, according to the most recent declared class...

    //More repeating codes here...
}
```

(It would save much time during development and in the future while maintaining if I could just use `include` to append this piece of code wherever it is needed. Hence my question.)

Comment: This is... a very weird thing to want to do. I can't imagine why you would want this. If you're dynamically loading a file containing a class definition based on some variable, you should know the name of the class based on the filename (and visa-versa) if you're using *any* kind of sensible naming scheme.

Comment: Yep, I know. I already had a solution for my specific problem (Which steveo255 has posted as well...), but as I stated in my question I am posing this question out of curiosity of what is possible or not. Thanks. (Also, unfortunately, there is no sensible naming scheme in the thing I am working on. It IS a flaw, but its been so before I started, so can't really do anything much about it at the moment..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably grab the last element returned by `get_declared_classes`, but something seems terribly, terribly wrong if you are trying to do this. Perhaps you could better explain your situation for more perspective on other ways to accomplish your goal.

Comment: You are right. I was wrong with my observation that `get_declared_classes` is sorted alphabetically and not chronologically. Thanks! As a side note, I have already solved my problem by utilizing PEAR-style naming convention. I no longer need to solve this problem lol. But I am accepting your answer as it solves the question as posed. :)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it works:

```
class MyClass {}
$class_name = 'MyClass';

//Repeating code:

if(isset($_REQUEST['fxn'], $class_name)) {
     $class = new $class_name();

    //More repeating codes here...
}
```

When you define the class you want to use, also define a variable with the name of the class.

Comment: This is what I am using currently, in fact. :)